# iOS - hideable UIView at the top of the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to create an info view that will show at the top of the screen and disappear after some time, and later it can show again and so on.

I have created UIView and set constraints:

```
topInfoView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.leadingAnchor)
topInfoView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: smainView.trailingAnchor)
topInfoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: HEIGHT)
```

Closed state:
    topInfoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.topAnchor, constant: -HEIGHT)

Open state:
    topInfoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.topAnchor, constant: 0)

where `mainView` is main `UIViewCcontroller` view.

I set `HEIGHT` as my user height + "status bar height" (bar with battery, Wifi etc). Problem is, that sometimes status bar height is 0 and my topInfoView is incorrectly placed. I am obtaining "status bar height" via this:

```
func statusBarHeight() -> CGFloat {
    let statusBarSize = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size
    return Swift.min(statusBarSize.width, statusBarSize.height)
}
```

but it sometimes not works (views are not inited?) and I am also not sure about new iPhone X, where status bar is solved differently. Is there any other way, without calculating the height?

Comment: If you are trying to get the view height in `viewDidLoad` then it might be wrong, because layout haven't been finished, get it in `viewDidLayoutSubview`

Comment: @Tj3n Thats why I am looking for a different solution, that is not "based" on status bar height directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the vertical stack view. Put the tableView and then your view vertically one after the another. Set the height of the table view. Keep the distribution property of stack view to **fill.** Create an outlet of the tableview. With this arrangement when you will hide the tableview, your view will fill the whole area. When you again set **isHidden property to false of table view** your table view and view will appear as original arrangement. You can animate while hiding and showing table view to give a good user experience.

Comment: Could you please post some sample code? I dont quite follow tableView.

Comment: Sorry any view. I thought its table view. Just wait for 5 mins.

Comment: Check [github repository with sample project](https://github.com/keshavRaj/HideableInfoViewForStackOverflowAnswer.git)